# C plugin for SonarQube

Tags: c, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, sonarqube

I'd like to use SonarQube to analyse C code for an open source project and integrate it into Jenkins.
Unfortunately the commercial C/C++ plugin is at EUR 7.000, which rules it out for a free software. I also saw the [community C++ plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=185073817). Does this also work well for C code?
If not, how could I configure SonarQube with suitable open source tools to get a legal free C plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

> This repository contains a SonarQube plugin implementing C++ support.

https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx

Comment: The plugin is able to analyse a cppcheck xml report. You have to generate report using cppcheck , then launch sonar analyse with sonnar-runner

Comment: See my answer here for how to do it fo rfree with sonar-cxx plugin mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299960/256770

Answer (score 1):

If your open source project is well-known, it can be analyzed for free on Nemo: http://nemo.sonarqube.org. Feel free to inquire on the developer mailing-list. See http://www.sonarqube.org/resources/join-our-community/