# sonarqube scanner properties file for C project

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonar qube for analysing C files. I am not able to see the complete smells listed for C/C++ after analysis. For example Divide by Zero error is not listed in the code smell.

My sonar scanner settings is reconfigured for C language using the option `sonar.language=c` and used C language specific tags like, `sonar.c.include directories`. I am getting Lexer errors for the C files.

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Is this a question about missing issues, or about how to resolve parser errors?

Comment: I was trying with "language=cxx" option initially and was observing the missing issue. Then later I tried to change the option to language=c to see if this get resolved or not. But I end up in a new issue called "lexer error".

Comment: I can provide more information about my requirement so that it helps to resolve the issue better.

Comment: My requirement is to run sonar on my code base (C). I want to see whether it catches the errors caught by PCLint by default or not. Do I need to run PC Lint separately to achieve this or not? While running the Sonar Qube with language=cxx option, I came across to see that only few cosmetic errors from the list is been caught after the analysis. I am attaching my sonar-scanner.properties file below for your reference. If you see any mistake please correct me. I didt get much help from any website for the properties file configuration for C projects.

Comment: sonar.projectKey=
sonar.projectName=
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.source=MyProjectPath
sonar.language=c
sonar.c.cFilesPatterns=*.c,*.h
sonar.c.suffixes.sources=MyProjectPath/file_1.c,MyProjectPath/file_2.c
sonar.c.suffixes.headers=MyProjectPath/file_1.h,MyProjectPath/file_2.h
sonar.c.includeDirectories=MyProjectPath/inc

Answer (score 2):

You can do analysis for free with [SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx). However, you need an external tool such as cppcheck in your dev machine to produce its results in XML format in a file.

Here is how I was able to do it:

1. Install `sonar-c-plugin`. For my version of sonarqube 5.6.1 I got this from https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/releases/download/cxx-0.9.8/sonar-c-plugin-0.9.8.jar
2. Configure the sonar.c.cppcheck.reportPath property in sonarqube server at Administration / General Settings / C(Community) / Cppcheck report(s). I set it to `build/cppcheck.xml`
3. Install [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/#download) in dev machine
4. Run cppcheck on your project and save results to build/cppcheck.xml
5. Create a sonar-project.properties file at root of your project see below for my sample
6. Install and run [sonar-scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScanner-Installation)

Here is my sonar-project.properties file:

```
sonar.host.url=http://mycompany.com:9000

sonar.projectKey=myprojectShortName
sonar.projectName=myprojectLongname
sonar.projectVersion=0.1

# Your relative path to source folder may be different 
sonar.sources=src/main/c

sonar.language=c

# The build-wrapper output dir
sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=bw-outputs

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

C an C++ are supported in SonarQube only with the paid Developer Edition or more expensive editions from SonarSource.  If you are running SonarQube Community Edition this may be why you are getting these lexer errors or otherwise unable to scan C files.

Comment: Not sure why the down-vote.  As of December 26, 2019, the SonarSource site indicates that C/C++ is NOT one of the supported languages in the free Community Edition (see Programming Language Coverage on the [Community](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/community/) page).  The [SonarQube 8.1 docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/cfamily/?src=sidebar) say "C/C++/Objective-C analysis is available as part of Developer Edition and above."